# JMeter mathematical function

Tags: jmeter

I have one random variable and one variable which I read from page. How can I subtract or multiply that two variables and where or in which component in JMeter.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Check out the functions page for [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). It has tons of cool math tools that you can plug anywhere in your script.

You'll most likely end up doing a [jexl](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl) command, which would look something like this: `${__jexl2(${var1}-${var2})}`

Comment: Thanks! I needed ${perpage} variable defined in JMeter and 
 ${__jexl(vars.get('perpage')-1)} worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me in Throughput Shaping Timer, while other methods (beanshell, javascript etc) were not working. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to perform division operation, but it's not working because ${var1} returns a String. Is there any way to do so, I can not use any pre processors as my case is specific.

Answer (score 3):

The above did not work for me. How ever i was able to resolve my problem with :

```
${__jexl(vars.get("YOUR_VARIABLE")+1)}
```

Comment: What version of jMeter did you use?